# Can always find compatible observables removing all degeneracies?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, operators, commutator, observables

When dealing with a Hermitian operator $A_1$ with degeneracies, it is a common practice to figure out all given quantum states, that finding other compatible operators, say $A_i$s, so that $[A_i,A_j]=0$ for all $i,j$. Then we MAY get all possible tuples of quantum numbers.

My question is: Can we always find compatible operators which make all eigenkets to be nondegenerate, respect to those operators? If so, is there any 'mathematical' proof? If not, can you give me a keyword of any counter-example?

**In other words:** If we have a maxiaml set of compatible operators, does it always guarantee non-degenerate?

Comment: @ACuriousMind The linked page does not fit to my question. I'm asking here that maximal compatible observables are always non-degenerate, or not, in sense of math; while they are talking about maximality.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean: The linked question and its answers show that a maximal set of commuting observables always is non-degenerate in its eigenvalues. How, exactly, is your question different? The "in other words" you just added is *exactly* the question in the duplicate.

Comment: @ACuriousMind yeah, you're right. i underatand your answer fully now. thank you very much!